# Show that $\binom{n}{1}-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{n}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Show that
>
> $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r} \right) = \frac{1}{n} $$

**My attempt.** I tried by taking the general term

$$ T_r = (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r} \right). $$

It looked somewhat like $\binom{n}{r} \int x^{r-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \binom{n}{r} \frac{x^r}{r} $, so  I took an expansion say

$$ T_1(r) = (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \left(1 + x + x^2 +  \cdots + x^{r-1} \right). $$

This simplifies to

$$ T_1(r) = (-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r} \frac{1-x^r}{1-x}. $$

I am struck after this I tried to rearrange this and done some simplification but I failed.

Please help me.

Comment: Note you've forgotten the signs in both statements of the problem...

Comment: `$(1 +  \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{r} )$` becomes much prettier than `(1 + $ \frac{1}{2} $ + $ \frac{1}{3} $ +$ \frac{1}{4} $ ............+$ \frac{1}{r} $)  `: $(1 +  \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{r} )$. It is also easier to type. Surround entire expressions in dollar signs, not each separate term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's summarize what you've already shown:  The given sum is equivalent to
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \int_0^1\left((-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\frac{1-x^r}{1-x}\right)\,dx$$

The first thing we'll do to this is make the sum start at $r=0$ instead of $r=1$ (which doesn't change anything since when $r=0$ the integrand is $0$), move the [finite] sum inside the integral, and then rearrange algebraically:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{r=1}^n \int_0^1&\left((-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\frac{1-x^r}{1-x}\right)\,dx = \sum_{r=0}^n \int_0^1\left((-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\frac{1-x^r}{1-x}\right)\,dx \\ &= \int_0^1 \sum_{r=0}^n \left((-1)^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\frac{1-x^r}{1-x}\right)\,dx \\ &= \int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1}\left(\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}(-x)^r-\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r\right)\,dx\end{align*}$$

Now both sums have the form $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} a^r = (1+a)^n$ by the binomial theorem, so by simplifying:
$$\int_0^1(1-x)^{-1}\left((1-x)^n - (1-1)^n\right)\,dx = \int_0^1 (1-x)^{n-1}\,dx = \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sum_{r=k}^n (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: Can u please mention  the second step more elaborately how did u write that

Comment: See the first identity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_sums).  You can derive it by applying upper negation twice, as shown in *Concrete Mathematics*, page 165, or via combinatorial proof, as shown in *Proofs That Really Count* (Identity 168).

Comment: I am really sorry  but I didn't understand what u have said I was asking how did u convert the first step I mean how did u interchange the sigma notations

Comment: Both double sums are equivalent to summing over $1\le k\le r\le n$.